# How can I arrange bars in pandas barplot after size of x values instead of count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to have a bar plot which counts the occurrences of different grades in af dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Grades.csv") 

df1 = df.sort_values(by=["Final Grade"])

valid_grades = ['12','10','7','4','2','0','-3']

df1['Final Grade'].value_counts().plot("bar")
```

What it returns a barplot with the most frequent grade in the left side of the plot and the least frequent in the right side.

I need it to draw the plot starting from -3 on the left side and 12 on the right.

[example of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7dBN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Add `sort_index`

```
df1['Final Grade'].value_counts().sort_index().plot("bar")
```

Comment: This command will just turn it around high counts on the right and low on the left.

I have tried this:

```
df1['Final Grade'].value_counts().sort_values(by=['Final Grade']).plot("bar")
```

but it gives me an error message saying:TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

Comment: I understand now you need `sort_index`... I updated the answer. `value_counts` returns a `pandas.Series` with `'Final Grade'` as the index. If you want to sort those, you need sort_index.

Comment: please try the new solution. that should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can select `valid_grades` from the resulted `Series` after `value_counts()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Final Grade': map(str, np.random.randint(-5, 15, 100))})
valid_grades = ['12','10','7','4','2','0','-3']
df1['Final Grade'].value_counts()[valid_grades].plot.bar()
```

[image]

If you want to reverse the x-axis you can add `[::-1]`:

```
df1['Final Grade'].value_counts()[valid_grades][::-1].plot.bar()
```

[image]